# FPDI function called from FPDF

Tags: php, pdf, fpdf, fpdi

This script loops over some JPG files and adds them to a PDF. After each JPG, I need to insert a PDF file, and as far as I can tell that can only be done with FPDI.

```
$GLOBALS['txt'] = 'Cover Text';  
$GLOBALS['mid_x'] = 11/2;  
$imagesFiles = glob('newimages/*.{png,jpg,jpeg,JPG,JPEG}', GLOB_BRACE);  
require('fpdf17/fpdf.php');  
require_once('fpdi/fpdi.php');  
class PDF extends FPDF {  
}  
$pdf=new PDF("L","in","Letter");  
$pdf->SetMargins(.1,.1,.1);  
$pdf->AddPage();  
$pdf->Image('newimages/02-CoverImage-2013.jpg', 0, 0, 11, 8.5, "JPG");  
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','',48);  
$pdf->SetTextColor(255,255,255); // White  
$pdf->Text($GLOBALS['mid_x']-$pdf-GetStringWidth($GLOBALS['txt'])/2,7,$GLOBALS['txt']);  
FOREACH ($imagesFiles as $filename) {
    $pdf->AddPage();  
    $pdf->Image($filename, 0, 0, 11, 8.5, "JPG");  
}  
$pdf->Output();
```

I can create a function with the following FPDI script to be called in the FOREACH loop above but how do I manage to insert the output of the FPDI function into the FPDF file?

```
$files = glob('pdfs/*.{pdf,PDF}', GLOB_BRACE);  
require_once('fpdf17/fpdf.php');  
require_once('fpdi/fpdi.php');  
$pdf = new FPDI();  
$pageNo = 1;  
$pageCount = $pdf->setSourceFile($files[3]);  
$templateId = $pdf->importPage($pageNo);  
$size = $pdf->getTemplateSize($templateId);  
if ($size['w'] > $size['h']) {  
    $pdf->AddPage('L', array($size['w'], $size['h']));  
} else {  
    $pdf->AddPage('P', array($size['w'], $size['h']));  
}  
$pdf->useTemplate($templateId);  
$pdf->Output();
```

Using `$pdf->addCalendarPage()` fails with:

> Call to undefined method PDF::addCalendarPage()

Using `$pdf->Image(addCalendarPage())` fails with:

> Cannot redeclare class PDF, in the FPDI function

Comment: Remember: FPDI extends FPDF. Instead of calling an FPDI method from within the FPDF class, have you tried instantiating the document as an FPDI? So in this case, change `extends FPDF` to `extends FPDI` and see what happens.

Comment: Second look: why even have a blank PDF class? Why not call a `new FPDI` directly instead?

Comment: @Mari M OK, that helped, thanks. Now I have to get the imported JPEGS and PDF's to match up in size.